# Configuration Manager Vs. Properties Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When **Configuration Manager** (or the appropriate boxes in the toolbar) has `x64` `Release` and the Properties **Build** has `x86` `Debug` (Without '`Active`') and F5 is clicked - VS follows **Configuration Manager**. So what is Properties **Build** for?

**Edit**:

This always determines the action:

[image]

This never does *even if it's not set to 'Active'* :

[image]

Checked with the following code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
#if (DEBUG)
            Text = "DEBUG";
#else
            Text = "Release";
#endif
            Text += Environment.Is64BitProcess;
        }
```

With Configuration Manager set to Debug+x86 (despite being an x64 computer), and the Build-tab under the project's properties set to Release+x64 (Not 'Active'). The result was: "DEBUGfalse".

So what is the latter (the Build tab) for?

Answer (score 3):

It simply lets you skip building a project in that particular configuration by unticking it.  Necessary if the project cannot or should not be built in that configuration. This is a pretty rare thing to do but can be useful if, say, you only want to build an installer in the Release build or have a project that cannot be built in the configuration.

The notion of having distinct platforms is important to unmanaged code, very unimportant to managed code.  Since managed code is naturally oblivious to the target architecture, the jitter takes care of it at runtime.  The name of the Platform also has nothing to do with the architecture the program can run in, the only setting that matters is Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.  And only for an EXE project.  Having a mismatch between that setting and the solution's Platform name has bewildered VS2010 users deeply.

The only sane setup for a managed solution is to have only *one* solution platform named AnyCPU.  The way it was done in VS versions prior to VS2010.  You'd only ever consider adding platforms when you build unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks. I assume your first paragraph is talking about the Configuration Manager (`Build` doesn't have a checkbox for disabling it). `the only setting that matters is Project + Properties, Build tab` - actually, as I wrote - Visual Studio follows the Configuration Manager, not the Build tab. (I tried that with a simple project that used `#if (DEBUG)`  and `Environment.Is64BitProcess` .

Comment: `managed code is naturally oblivious to the target architecture` - I assume you meant that `Any CPU` would work on both, not that it is really _completely_ oblivious because the reason I used a different platform is because Ngen wasn't working in `Any CPU` nor on `x64` (As in my other question which you answered) - and changing to `x86` solved that.

Comment: No, only the Platform target setting matters.  Different configurations can have different settings for this option, you can get it right by accident.  All of which is not relevant to ngen, the version you run determines for which architecture it generates native images.  As long as your EXE project is AnyCPU, the 64-bit version of ngen.exe will generate the correct native images on a 64-bit machine.  If it is forced to x86 for some reason then you must use the 32-bit version of ngen.exe.

Comment: OK. I think I figured out this apparent disagreement - By `Properties Build` I'm _not_ referring to what is shown when I click `Build` -> `Configuration Manager` -> `a table with 'Platform' and 'Build' amongst others`. Rather - I'm referring to what is shown when I double-click `Properties in Solution Explorer` -> `Build (tab)` -> `Top line has 'Configuration' and 'Build'` which are nominally set to **Active (...)**. _That_ (the latter) is the one that seems to have no effect even if it's _not_ set to `Active`. (Edited in the question to make it clear.)